# Trying to capture two lines before a found regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to figure out how to capture a regex and the two lines previous to it.

Example:

```
Santa Claus
North Pole, North Pole
H0H 0H0
```

The regex I have is for the Postal Code `[a-z]{1}\d{1}[a-z]{1}\s\d{1}[a-z]{1}\d{1}`

I want to be able to capture that result and the previous two lines as well using on regex expression.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `(.*\n.*\n[a-z]\d[a-z]\s\d[a-z]\d)` seems to work..

Comment: @JoshCrozier Could you post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
(.*\n.*\n[a-z]\d[a-z]\s\d[a-z]\d)
```

[**Example Here**](https://regex101.com/r/rN3xF4/1)

- `.*\n.*\n` will match all characters on the previous two lines.
- `[a-z]\d[a-z]\s\d[a-z]\d` - I removed `{1}` after each character class (since only one will be matched by default, this is redundant).

You may also need to add the case-insensitive `i` flag since `[a-z]` will only match lowercase characters. Otherwise that should be replaced with `[A-Za-z]` to catch the capital letters in the postal codes.

Comment: Thank you, Worked like a charm.